# What is important in the Luria-Latarjet effect?

Tags: genetics, microbiology, virology, history

In the seminal paper

> Luria, S.E. and Latarjet, R. (1964) “Ultraviolet irradiation of
> bacteriophage during intracellular growth”. Proceedings of the
> National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America, vol. 52,
> pp. 1521-1529.

Luria and Latarjet reported that the sensitivity of phages within infected bacteria decreased sharply after about 10 min p.i.

They assumed a "screening hypothesis" that assumed that the viral genomes (sensitive to irradiation) were shielded from UV light by "some ultraviolet-absorbing material" (namely the capsid".

This paper led to the so-called "Luria-Laterjet effect" (e.g., doi: 10.1016/0042-6822(68)90011-1 and doi: 10.1017/s0016672300031499). Thus, it must be a relevant feature in virology.

**What is the underlying feature of this effect?**

I understand that it is proof of a viral eclipse (virions are formed sometimes after infection, albeit they might still not be infectious). Still, some papers raised the involvement of DNA repair (which is usually not mentioned in modern virology text covering viral replication).

Is there something else that this effect explains?

Thank you

Comment: I only see two papers which call this the "Luria-Latarjet effect", both of which are the ones you provided as DOI numbers. Two papers is tiny output for a "feature of virology" or it would be more widely studied. Luria and Latarjet found that during infection the sensitivity to DNA damage decreased and then increased again as new phage was produced. I fail to see any feature that isn't explained by Hyman's work.

Comment: Fair enough, I though there was more to it. Thanks

Comment: Can I add an addition to the question? IS the L-L effect a proof for the presence of restriction enzymes? Luria made such a preliminary discovery soon after this work with Latarjet but I did not understand if he was talking about the same subject (DOI: 10.1128/jb.64.4.557-569.1952 )...

Comment: No, I don't think so - though it could make a good new question. The L-L effect described is due to formation of the viral DNA/RNA - when it is in short lengths it is less susceptible to damage from radiation, which has little to do with REs would be my guess.